# Is «ндравиться» archaic or just geographical?

Tags: этимология, произношение

Having traveled in the rural area around Penza I found that almost all the people say «ндравиться» rather than «нравиться», for example:

— Мне ндравится сегодняшняя погода.

Is it some archaic pronunciation or is it just something that evolved specifically in that geographical area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Эпентеза (неэтимологическое, по чисто фонетическим причинам, возникновение звуков посередь слова) в русском языке не ограничивается словом *ндравиться* и, насколько мне известно, не локализована территориально — слова *энтот* (этот) и *энтак* (этак), *постле* (после) вы наверняка слышали и в своем краю. Ту же природу имеет /n/ в словах *преце**н**дент* и *компроме**н**тировать*, которые вы иногда можете встретить даже там, где орфоэпическую норму блюдут — на телевидении, например.

Ничего архаичного в ней тем более нет — вы сами воочию убедились, что она по сей день встречается в живой речи.

Таким образом, это не архаично и не географично, а «просторечно» (звучит снобистски, но это термин).

Кстати, это *ндравиться* легко найти в литературе, где оно наряду с другими особенностями речи используется именно для демонстрации социального происхождения героя:

> У нас у всех крест на шее... Франчишке Лефорту, что ли, этот крест не *ндравится*? [А. К. Толстой. Петр Первый]
>
> — У Еракина нынче электричество зажигали, — сказал он. — Не *ндравится* мне! [Чехов. Архиерей.]
>
> — Кожа тебе не по скусу? Морщинки тебе, морда собачья, не *ндравятся*? Перед народом меня страмить выдумал... [Зощенко. Баба.]

Answer (score 2):

The verb **"нравиться"** comes from the noun **"нрав"** (temper, disposition), old-Russian **"нъравъ"**, which already appears in documents of the XI-XII centuries. I don't think its pronunciation changed with the time.

The incorrect pronunciation **"нДравиться"** seems to be really old and it used to be quite common among **illiterate people** in the XIX century. You can see this verb in the book "Penal servitude. Criminals" by Vlas Doroshevich, a Russian journalist and writer of the XIX century.

The woman who uses this word in the book comes from Kostroma, a town in the North of Russia, so I don't think this pronunciation evokes specifically in the geographical area of Penza.

To put it short, **it doesn't depend on the geographical area, but on the social class and level of education of people.**

The verb "нДравиться" is now used to speak in a funny way about something you like (people who use the verb know it's incorrect):

Мне нДравится э́тот музон.
I like this cool music (not serious, joking).